# how to highlight a choice in html when an user clicks the button (before submitted the choice) using jquery

Tags: python, jquery, html, django

Hi could you help me to solve the following problem?
I am writing a web application in django. I would like to achieve the follow function in a page: When the user click a radio button, that choice would be made highlighted. As shown in this graph:

[page illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwH9Q.png)

in the form.py I have

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    ANSWER_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Lottery 1'),
        (2, 'Lottery 2'),
    )
    answer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ANSWER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    question = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

My html is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <head>
      <title>Two lotteries</title>
   </head>
<body>
       <table BORDER=1 WIDTH="40%" HEIGHT="40%" border = "1" bordercolor = "green">
         <tr>
            <td>  </td>
            <th>State 1</th>
               <th>State 2</th>
               <th>State 3</th>
         </tr>

           <tr bgcolor = "white" >
            <td>Lottery 1</td>
            <td>{{ problem.0 }}{{ sltlottery }}</td>
             <td>{{ problem.1 }} </td>
             <td>{{ problem.2 }}</td>
         </tr>

           <tr>
            <td>Lottery 2</td>
            <td> {{ problem.3 }} </td>
             <td> {{ problem.4 }} </td>
             <td> {{ problem.5 }} </td>
         </tr>

      </table>

   </body>
<form action=" " method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input name="sellottery" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I did a bit search online people suggested to use jquery to read the value of the clicked button.

```
<script>
$('input[name="sellottery"]:checked').val();
</script>
```

Could anyone let me know if this above line is going to return a value of either 1 or 2 ? and how can I write the following logic statements in java script and pass it to html: when the value is 1, bgcolor = "yellow"?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You can do this with CSS on the client-side. Really more of a CSS question than a django question. But see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49514219/5747944) on a similar question.

Comment: Hi thanks for this. But my problem is I need to somehow read the value of the choice when the user click the radio button but before that choice to be Submit. When the user click one radio button, the associated choice would be highlighted. Then the user can also click the other radio button to see that choice be highlighted. Only after the user click a Submit button that choice is submitted.

Comment: @sytech Hi I have edited the question, could you have a look again? Thanks!